# Is it possible to display element index as a comment?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, comments

I am initializing a list with data using a collection initializer. Since there's quite a few elements in the list it is hard to keep track of the index of each element. As such I have been keeping track of the index manually using comments, but this leads to extra work keeping the indices up to date. Is there a tool or script that will automatically do this for me? Alternately is there any solution not involving comments?

```cs
var list = new List<Element>
{
    new Element() // 0 <-- I want to keep this number up to date
    {
        // Data
    }
    new Element() // 1
    {
        // Data
    }
    new Element() // 2
    {
        // Data
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Silky, Welcome to stackoverflow. Do you want this indices while initializing `List<Element>` or in code while using this `List<Element>`?

Comment: What is the value of adding the comment of the index the object will be in the list? You can always debug using visual studio and check the indices in the list if needed.

Comment: Thank you for answering. While it is indeed easy to find the index of an element, my problem lies in finding the corresponding element in the actual code. It's always a hassle to scroll through the entire list to find a 

The list is used to describe a tutorial sequence and is subject to frequent changes.

Comment: To Prasad: In the code. That is to say, I want to quick way of seeing which index an element has in the collection initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore using `Dictionaries` for this purpose, though it's hard to know what you're hoping to do with your `List`. A `Dictionary` is a collection of `key`s and `value`s and you can get to the `value` via the key. For example:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Element>();
myDictionary.Add(1, new Element{
        PropertyA = "sss",
        PropertyB = 1234,
    })
```

etc. You can then get and set the `key`s as needed.

Not certain, but your question kind of "feels" like a dictionary type question. You shouldn't be using indices on `List`s in the structured way you seem to be wanting to

see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The list is used as a tutorial sequence and as such a dictionary wouldn't quite be applicable.